# Why is npm run not working under alpine linux?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, alpine-linux, busybox

I'm trying to run `npm` run test and `npm` run server, as defined in my `package.json`

```js
  "scripts": {
    "server": "app/server.js",
    "build": "npm run test && npm run build server",
    "test": "test/default.js"
  },
```

However, both fail as if `npm` didn't recognize any syntax. It is worth noting that while `app/server.js` was generated from ts without any warnings with `tsc`, and `test/default.js` was written from scratch in JS.

```js
npm run server

> my-project@1.0.0 server
> app/server.js

app/server.js: line 1: use strict: not found
app/server.js: line 2: exports.__esModule: not found
app/server.js: line 3: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

```
npm run test                                                                     
> my-project@1.0.0 test
> test/default.js

test/default.js: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

```
head -n 7 test/default.js

const request = require('supertest');
const chai = require('chai');
const app = require('./server');

const expect = chai.expect;

describe('GET /vehicles/:id', () => {
```

```
head -n 10 app/server.js

"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var express_1 = require("express");
var body_parser_1 = require("body-parser");
var pg_1 = require("pg");

// Create a new Express app
var app = (0, express_1["default"])();
// Parse JSON bodies
app.use(body_parser_1["default"].json())
```

I have run `npm` install with no issues. The linter does not report any issues. I'm running `npm` 9.2.0 and node 18.12.1. However, the issue also occurs on Manjaro, so it might not be an issue specific to Alpine, but something wrong with my code. In my tsconfig.json I've set it to use es2020.
From my npm config:

```
globalignorefile = "/etc/npmignore"
prefix = "/usr/local"
python = "/usr/bin/python3"

ignore-scripts = false
script-shell = "/bin/zsh"
```

I have tried running the whole thing under Docker and on a different machine, so might be an issue with my code. I know `require` is not natively supported by TypeScript, but the files are JS, so I don't know what's the issue. Sorry if my question sounds stupid, but earlier I've run TypeScript using Deno without the whole hassle of transpiling it to JS and used Node for 'pure' JS only.

Comment: Your scripts probably aren't shell-executable. Try `"server": "node app/server.js"`

Comment: Use official node docker image. https://hub.docker.com/_/node
The official Node.js image that already has all the tools and packages that we need to run a Node.js application.

Comment: yep, simply adding 'node' before my scripts paths solved the issue